# Extending Reader Class: How to write close()?

Tags: java, file-io

In Java, I am trying to write a subclass for the abstract [Reader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) class. I am trying to implement Reader's close() method. The subclass I intend to write, Reader2, will translate the input from the original Reader (obtained by calling ReaderObj.read()) into something else, so that calling read() on a Reader2 object will output the translated character.

For example, this would translated all lowercase 'a', 'b', and 'c' characters into their corresponding capitals, and leave the rest unchanged:

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
Reader2 translated = new Reader2(in, "abc", "ABC");
while (true) {
    int x = translated.read;
    if (x == -1) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.print((char x));
}
```

I have already implemented read(), but I don't know how to implement close().

According to the documentation, the close() method is supposed to close the stream and throw an IOException. But I don't know how to close a stream, or throw an IOException. How exactly would I rewrite close()?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? And, you don't _have_ to throw, you are just permitted to if necessary.

Comment: What are you writing a reader for? How to "close the stream" will depend 100% on this.

Comment: I am trying to implement Reader's close() method. The subclass I intend to write, Reader2, will translate the input from the original Reader (obtained by calling ReaderObj.read()) into something else.

Comment: If you dont even know how to throw an exception, you probably shouldnt be writing a reader subclass. I think your best bet is to do a lot of studying in java first.

Comment: What is your reader _for_?

Comment: Grab source of Apache Commons IO, and read some examples.

Comment: @bmargulies, I updated the post; let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: If your goal is to translate the input from the original Reader into something else, you should extend [`FilterReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterReader.html) and override its `read` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Reader in = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
Reader2 translated = new Reader2(in, "abc", "ABC");
```

You create an input stream reader and pass it into your translated reader. To close your Reader2 instance you only have to invoke the close() method on the in Reader you passed to your Reader2 instance by the constructor `new Reader2(in, "abc", "ABC");`.

```
public void close() { in.close(); }
```

Comment: How exactly does the original reader get closed? I looked at the documentation, and Reader's close is abstract - it has no implementation. I looked at the superclass of Reader - the interface Closeable - and it too has no implementation for close.

Comment: @毛泽东: it doesn't matter how the original reader gets closed; just let `class InputStreamReader` do that on its own. You don't have to worry about it because your `Reader2` is **not** a subclass of `Reader`. That's because having an instance of `Reader` in your class, does not mean that your class suddenly becomes a `Reader` itself. Otherwise, the fact your house has a TV in would mean that your house is a TV as well :)